# clustering in each group

Tags: r, data-mining, data-manipulation

```
Here is a list of persons with their scorecards(Z)
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(X = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 40, replace = TRUE),Y= sample    (c("Graduate", "Non-graduate"), 40, replace  = TRUE),Z =10*runif(40))
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% group_by(X,Y) %>% arrange(X,Y)
df1
```

(df1 > its initials are the image)

[image]

In each group (female graduate, female non-graduate, male graduate, male non-graduate ) , we want to create clusters. Finally we need to give a unique cluster id to each person. It means output file is an array of clusterid.

Comment: what's you question, and what have you tried?

Comment: Please **don't cross-post**: duplicated at http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/10735/924

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
hc <- hclust(dist(scale(data.matrix(df1))))
plot(hc)
View(newdf <- cbind(df1, cluster=cutree(hc, h = 0.5)))
```

`data.matrix` converts your two factors to its numeric representation, `scale` gives equal weight to X, Y, and Z. And `cutree` gets the cluster for every observation by cutting the dendrogram at a height of 0.5.